# SQL query to select the latest records with a distinct subject

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery, aggregate-functions

I am using SQL Server and have a table set up like below:

```
| id | subject | content | moreContent | modified   |
| 1  | subj1   | aaaa    | aaaaaaaaaaa | 03/03/2015 |
| 2  | subj1   | bbbb    | aaaaaaaaaaa | 03/05/2015 |
| 3  | subj2   | cccc    | aaaaaaaaaaa | 03/03/2015 |
| 4  | subj1   | dddd    | aaaaaaaaaaa | 03/01/2015 |
| 5  | subj2   | eeee    | aaaaaaaaaaa | 07/02/2015 |
```

I want to select the latest record for each subject heading, so the records to be returned would be:

```
| id | subject | content | moreContent | modified   |
| 2  | subj1   | bbbb    | aaaaaaaaaaa | 03/05/2015 |
| 3  | subj2   | cccc    | aaaaaaaaaaa | 03/03/2015 |


SELECT Subject, MAX(Modified) FROM [CareManagement].[dbo].[Careplans] GROUP BY Subject
```

I could do a query like the one above, but I want to preserve all of the content from the selected rows. To return the content columns I would need to apply an aggregate function, or add them to the group by clause which wouldn't give me the desired effect. 
I have also looked at nested queries but not found a successful solution yet. If anyone could assist that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELECT id, subject,  content, moreContent, modified
FROM (
   SELECT id, subject,  content, moreContent, modified,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY subject 
                             ORDER BY modified DESC) AS rn
   FROM [CareManagement].[dbo].[Careplans] ) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

`rn = 1` will return each record having the latest `modified` date per `subject`. In case there are two or more records sharing the same 'latest' date and you want *all* of these records returned, then you might have a look at `RANK()` window function.

Answer (score 1):

Using ROW_NUMBER this becomes pretty simple.

```
with myCTE as
(
    select id
        , Subject
        , content
        , morecontent
        , Modified
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY [Subject] order by Modified desc) as RowNum
    from [CareManagement].[dbo].[Careplans]
)

select id
    , Subject
    , content
    , morecontent
    , Modified
from myCTE
where RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`rank`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) window function to retrieve only the latest record:

```
SELECT id, subject, content, moreContent, modified
FROM   (SELECT id, subject, content, moreContent, modified,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY subject ORDER BY modified DESC) AS rk
        FROM   [CareManagement].[dbo].[Careplans]) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```